# Can structural typing work with generics?

Tags: scala, type-erasure

I have an interface defined using a structural type like this:

```
trait Foo { 
  def collection: { 
    def apply(a: Int) : String 
      def values() : collection.Iterable[String]
    }
  }
}
```

I wanted to have one of the implementers of this interface do so using a standard mutable HashMap:

```
class Bar { 
   val collection: HashMap[Int, String] = HashMap[Int, String]()
}
```

It compiles, but at runtime I get a NoSuchMethod exception when referring a Bar instance through a Foo typed variable.  Dumping out the object's methods via reflection I see that the HashMap's apply method takes an Object due to type erasure, and there's some crazily renamed generated apply method that does take an int.  Is there a way to make generics work with structural types? Note in this particular case I was able to solve my problem using an actual trait instead of a structural type and that is overall much cleaner.

Comment: Could you add an example of how you use this and get the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that the apply method parameter is causing you grief because it requires some implicit conversions of the parameter (`Int => Integer`). Implicits are resolved at compile time, the `NoSuchMethodException` is likely a result of these missing implicits.

Attempt to use the `values` method and it should work since there are no implicits being used.

I've attempted to find a way to make this example work but have had no success so far.